# Print the string between two parentheses

Tags: sed, grep, perl

I have file with these lines

```
G8 = P(G1,G3)
G9 = P(G3,G4)
G12 = P(G2,G9)
G15 = P(G9,G5)
G16 = P(G8,G12)
G17 = P(G12,G15)
```

I need the output as

```
G1,G3
G3,G4
.....
```

How can I do it with sed/grep command or using perl?

Comment: The question is under-specified: What if there are parenteses inside parentheses? Assume that does not happen?

Answer (score 35):

A few other ways:

- `sed`

  ```
  sed 's/.*(\(.*\))/\1/' file
  ```
- perl

  ```
  perl -pe 's/.*\((.*)\)/$1/' file
  ```

  or

  ```
  perl -lanF"[()]" -e 'print $F[1]' file
  ```

  or

  ```
  perl -pe 's/.*\((.+?)\).*/$1/;' file
  ```
- `awk`

  ```
  awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' file
  ```
- shell

  ```
  while IFS="()" read a b; do echo "$b"; done < file
  ```

Comment: would you tell more about how awk method works ?, its easy to remember too

Comment: @satch_boogie the `-F` lets you chose what character(s) awk will use to split the line into fields. Here, I am giving it a character class (`[]`) consisting of opening and closing parentheses. So it will split the line on `(` and on `)`. As a result, the 2nd field will be the contents of the parentheses. E.g, with the string `G8 = P(G1,G3)foo`, `$1` will be `G8 = P`, `$2` will be `G1,G3` and `$3` would be `foo`.

Answer (score 9):

There is more than one way to do it:

```
perl -nle 'print $1 if /\((.*)\)/' file
```

or:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {print $1}' RS='(' FS=')' file
```

Answer (score 7):

```
grep -oP '\(\K[^)]+' file
```

That looks for the opening parenthesis, ignores it, then prints all the non-close-parenthesis characters that follow.

Requires GNU grep

Comment: This solution captures characters between parenthesis regardless of any characters that follow the closing parentheses and ignores lines that have no parentheses. sed and awk solutions require that lines without parentheses be filtered out separately.

Answer (score 6):

`sed 's/^.*(//;s/)$//' /path/to/file`

To break this down:

`sed` is the `s`tream `ed`itor.  `'s/^.*(//;s/)$//'` is the script being sent to `sed`, which breaks down as the following:

```
s/^.*(//    substitute nothing for the beginning of any line (`^`) followed by anything up until an open-paren (`(`)
s/)$//      substitute nothing for a close-paren (`)`) followed immediately by the end of a line
```

Answer (score 2):

> A simple cut solution:
>
> $ cat test01 |cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'(' '{print $NF}' file | sed 's/)//g'
```

Comment: Better to use `awk -F"[()]" '{print $2}' file` as in [terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/108256/72456)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cut

```bsh
cat file | cut -d"(" -f2 | cut -d")" -f1
> G1,G3
> G3,G4
> G2,G9
> G9,G5
> G8,G12
> G12,G15
```