# Extract the first percentage from a string

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have a string:

```
Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%)
```

How do I extract just the `99%` (number within first parenthesis) but not the `0`?

Comment: Where do you have this string? In a file? In a shell variable? In a database?

Comment: You should clarify if you want to match "the first percentage expression of a string" or "the first number within parentheses". Also what have you tried so far, have you used `grep`? (I see you tagged grep)

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '[()]' '{print $2}' <<< "$string"
```

Output:

```
99%
```

Note: This will actually output anything within the first `(...)`, no matter what it is.

Comment: True, but I don't see in the question that it should be verified. I added a note to my answer.

Comment: This will not necessarily match anything within the first `()`. For example for this line: `x=$(command "text(10%)")` it will match `command "text`.

Comment: you are right, it won't work correctly for nested `(...)`.

Comment: @αғsнιη actually, the question states it is looking for "number within first parenthesis". So  given that things like `-45%`, `0.84%` and `145%` can all be valid percentages, I think the only thing we can do is follow the question and use the parentheses.

Comment: @pLumo  It is already been answered , duplicate question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108250/print-the-string-between-two-parentheses

Comment: Well ... true =) Good find then. Not sure if the Question can be considered a duplicate then. I would say "depends" :-D

Answer (score 2):

```
string='Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%)'
grep -oP '^.*?\(\K([0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]+)?|100)%(?=\))' <<<"$string"
```

please note that this returns the first valid percentage found within `(...)` in case first founded pattern was not valid, if will return next hope.

---

This extract all possible percentage in a string matched with the same pattern as above:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\()([1-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]+)?|100)%(?=\))' <<<"$string"
```

change `[1-9]` to `[0-9]` if you also want to match `0%` as well as those were with leading zero like `00%`~`09%`.

`[0-9]` matches only single digit in almost all locates.
`[0-9]?` matches one-or-zero of the same; replace this with `[0123456789]` if you want to match only English/ASCII digits.

Comment: Why use `[0-9][0-9]|100` instead of just `\d+`? Also, why is `0.4%` not a valid percentage?

Comment: @terdon `\d` also can be used but because I use different `[0-9]` and `[1-9]` somewhere and explained something about that, so I preferred to don't touch that part; about `0.4%` that was good point and that's definitely a valid perc, and I have updated my answer to match on those perc too; thank you

Comment: Why not simply `grep` everything until the next `)` ? -->  `grep -Po '^.*?\(\K[^)]*'`

Comment: @pLumo to validate that's percentage nothing else

Comment: The thing is, depending on the data and what is being calculated, 345% is also perfectly valid. I just think that looking for a string of numbers, 0 or one `.` and a `%` is the only thing we can rely on.

Answer (score 2):

If that string is in a shell variable, to extract the first sequence of decimal digits followed by a `%`.

With `zsh`:

```
$ string='Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%)'
$ print ${(MS)string#<->%}
99%
```

(or `<1->%` if you want to extract the first non-null percentage)

With `bash`:

```
$ string='Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%)'
$ [[ $string =~ [0123456789]+% ]] && echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
99%
```

(or `0*[123456789][0123456789]*%` for the first non-null percentage).

POSIXly:

```
awk -- '
  BEGIN{
    if (match(ARGV[1], /[0123456789]+%/))
      print substr(ARGV[1], RSTART, RLENGTH)
  }' "$string"
```

(Again `0*[123456789][0123456789]*%` for the first non-null percentage).

For the `bash` and POSIX ones, `$string` must contain valid text in your locale.

Answer (score -1):

This will help you to get the desired output

**Approach 1 :**

```
var='Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%)'
echo ${var#*(} | sed -E 's/%*$/ /g' | sed 's/).*//'
```

**Output :**

99%

**Approach 2 :**

```
echo "Identities = 99/100 (99%) total 0/0 (0%) #*)" | sed -E 's/%*$/ /g' | sed 's/).*//' | cut -d'(' -f2
```

**Output :**

99%

Comment: So how is this different from my solution?